# How to access typed data from out Renderscript allocation?

Tags: android, renderscript

I create typed RS allocations this way:

```
mRS = RenderScript.create(mContext);
Element.Builder eb = new Element.Builder(mRS);
eb.add(Element.F32_3(mRS), "xyz");
eb.add(Element.F32_2(mRS), "uv");
Element eStride_XYZUV = eb.create();

mInAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS, eStride_XYZUV, animLand.getArray().length / 5);
mOutAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS, eStride_XYZUV, animLand.getArray().length / 5);
```

`animLand.getArray()` is an array of `float`. I can copy data to input allocation:

```
mInAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(animLand.getArray());
```

However, when I try to retrieve data from out allocation this way:

```
mOutAllocation.copyTo(animLand.getArray());
```

I get exception:

```
android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: 32 bit float source does not match allocation type null
```

How can I access data from output `Allocation` with array of my custom `Element`? There are methods to copy to arrays/bitmaps but only for primitive `Element` types.

It works if I use primitive `F32` type but I would like to use typed data:

```
mInAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.F32(mRS), animLand.getArray().length);
mOutAllocation = Allocation.createSized(mRS, Element.F32(mRS), animLand.getArray().length);
...
mInAllocation.copyFromUnchecked(animLand.getArray());
...
mOutAllocation.copyTo(animLand.getArray());
```